# OpenCL: use write_imagef to set CL_INTENSITY cl_float image pixel value

Tags: opencl

I am new to OpenCL and C++. I am trying to use `write_imagef` to edit pixels in a CL_INTENSITY cl_float image. The working environment is Mac OS X (so OpenCL 2.0?), Eclipse Luna with GCC 4.9 setup.

## Working examples

I have got copy image2 from image1 `__kernel` working as below (main.cpp [link](http://www.pasteall.org/54541/cpp)):

```
__kernel void image_copy(__read_only image2d_t image1, __write_only image2d_t image2) {
    const int2 loc = (int2) (get_global_id(0),get_global_id(1));
    const sampler_t sampler=CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;
    float4 pixel = read_imagef(image1, sampler, loc);
    write_imagef(image2, loc, pixel);
}
```

Besides, a `float` variable in `write_imagef()` would also work (probably because CL_INTENSITY is single channel), for example:

```
write_imagef(image2, loc, pixel.x);
```

Or

```
float p = pixel.x;
write_imagef(image2, loc, p);
```

Both also produce copied `image2` from `image1`.

## Not working examples (my questions)

When I try to edit the output image instead of straight copying with `write_imagef`, it always failed (kernel successfully compiled but cannot produce an output image). I think the error is because the pixel values are not edited right:

```
write_imagef(image2, loc, (float4)(1,1,1,1));
```

Or

```
write_imagef(image2, loc, (float4)(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f));  // not quite different
```

Or

```
const float4 foo = (float4)(1,1,1,1);
write_imagef(image2, loc, foo);
```

Operation basing on `float4` vector by `read_imagef` from inputfile also cannot produce output image:

```
float4 pixel = read_imagef(image1, sampler, loc);
pixel = pixel * 2;
write_imagef(image2, loc, pixel);
```

Or

```
float4 pixel = read_imagef(image1, sampler, loc);
float p = pixel.x * 2;  
write_imagef(image2, loc, p);
```

Are there any special format I ignored for CL_INTENSITY image? Because I found many examples show that `(float4)(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)` would work with RGB image.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? Did the kernel not compile, or product unexpected results? Have you verified that your device supports CL_INTENSITY format images for the data? I can confirm that write_imagef expects a float4 parameter even if the image is single channel, so your attempts to use just float are not correct.

Comment: @Dithermaster Thanks. "Failed" means `kernel` compiled but not producing output image. I think my devices support CL_INTENSITY, because there are successful examples I ran. And attempts to use `float` as pixel value have also succeeded. However, further modification beyond simple image copy failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Because `image1` & `image2` are both 2D arrays

I found the answer myself that the arrays were created in this way:

```
int j;
float** newarray = (float**) malloc(dimx*sizeof(float*));
for (j = 0 ; j < dimx ; j++)
    newarray[j] = (float*) malloc(dimy*sizeof(float));
```

I knew that passing 2D array to kernel is "NO NO", but I thought as an `Image Object` it should work, which still turned out to be "NO".

Once I make `image1` and `image2` 1D arrays, `write_imagef(image2, loc, 1);` and `write_imagef(image2, loc, pixel.x*2);` etc. would all work (for `CL_INTENSITY` is single channel, a `float` value would also do).

I found this out by attempting to pass host 2D array to `Buffer Object` (1D array) and then read it out back to another host 2D array. Still simple straight copy works, while any further attempt of operations would fail to produce an array readable to the machine.

So the conclusion is I made a mistake by passing 2D arrays to kernel. And 2D array is possible to be passed to kernel, and read back. However, it is very fragile.